# How to Store a data From JSON file into a JSON Store

Tags: extjs

Hi i have a JSON file which contains

```
{
   "result": [
      {
         "urlFeedCategoryValue": "Language",
         "urlFeedName": "DB2",
         "urlId": "language_DB2",
         "urlFeedLink": "http://www-947.ibm.com/systems/support/myfeed/xmlfeeder.wss?feeder.requid=feeder.create_public_feed&feeder.feedtype=RSS&feeder.maxfeed=25&OC=SSEPDU&feeder.subdefkey=swgimgmt&feeder.channel.title=DB2 Connect&feeder.channel.descr=The latest updates about DB2 Connect",
         "urlFeedCategory": "1",
         "urlFeedTimeStamp": "2012-04-17-03:04:27"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now i want to read this JSON file and store it in the JSONStore of Extjs

Plz help me how to acheive thi

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

This is not especially a problem of Ext. 
Do you have any serverside backend? Then I would suggest opening and preparing the JSON-File there.